# ARM-NEON: Conditional register swapping based on parameters

Tags: performance, optimization, assembly, arm, neon

I am writing a piece of subroutine in NEON for image processing which does color swapping, i.e., I sequentialy load the R,G,B channels from an array, and depending on some configuration, permute some of them.

There are as maximum 6 permutes

```
  (RGB) -> { (RGB),(RBG),(GRB),(GBR),(BRG),(BGR) }
```

The most efficient way would be to have a separate subroutine for each case and the corresponding VSWP instructions. As the Subroutine will do several other things, I would prefer to keep everything in just one sub, even if it is not so efficient,

Also have read that conditional execution and branching is not advisable. So, if I want to have it in a block with branchless code, the only thing coming to my mind is

```
New_R = a(0)*R+a(1)*G+a(2)*B
New_G = a(3)*R+a(4)*G+a(5)*B
New_B = a(6)*R+a(7)*G+a(8)*B
```

where only one a(i) in each row and column will be =1 each time, and the rest will be =0

Question: Any smarter way to do it, having in mind that it has to be coded to NEON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VTBL.8` is the most powerful tool in NEON to swap bytes.

Loading 3x8 bytes to registers d0,d1,d2 would look like

```
  R G B R G B R G | B R G B R G B R | G B R G B R G B |
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7   8 9 a b c d e f ....            17

VTBL d3, { d0,d1,d2 }, d6  ;; select bytes to d3 from d0,d1,d2 based on d6
VTBL d4, { d0,d1,d2 }, d7
VTBL d5, { d0,d1,d2 }, d8
```

where d6,d7,d8 encode the positions to read in the new bytes. 
e.g. '0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7' for the original permutation and '0 2 1 3 5 4 6 8', '7 ...' to swap G and B. The constant vectors d6..d8 need to be loaded just once in the beginning of the routine.

Another possibility is to encode the following sequence with interleaved read;

```
VLD3.8 { d0,d1,d2 }, [r0]    ; // Read R, G, B to separate registers
VLD3.8 { d3,d4,d5 }, [r0]    ; // Make a second copy (or use some other instruction)

VBIT d3, d1, d6              ; // d3 is now either R or G
VBIT d4, d2, d7              ; // d4 is now either G or B
VBIT d5, d0, d8              ; // d5 is now either B or R

VBIT d0, d4, d9              ; // d0 is now R or (G or B)
VBIT d1, d5, d10             ; // d1 is now G or (B or R)
VBIT d2, d3, d11             ; // d2 is now B or (R or G)
```

Even though 6 registers for the condition codes are used in the example, 3 independent registers should be enough -- one can also use VBIF if reversed logic needs to be used.

Comment: No words. My previous question had just been about VTBL but simply hadn't thought that it can also be used for permutations. Thanks

Comment: I don't think this is the most efficient method, since VTBL is rather complex and doesn't execute in single clock. It's easy though. You might want to experiment with _interleaved read_ VLD3.8 to separate RGB to different channels, d1=R, d2=G, d3=B, and use VBIT or VSEL to copy full registers. Using `VLD3.8 {d0, d2, d4}, [r0]!; VLD3.8 {d1, d3, d5}, [r0]!` allows allocation the full register _q0_ to red channel.

Comment: Yes, I already do interleaved reads and adapted your previous answer to this case. But I can't get to see how to use VBIT o VSEL to work for a general case, i.e., in the previous answer I only had to load once d6..d8. Sorry if what I am asking is obvious, I'm quite new.

Comment: I like the VBIT option, thanks. Also, perhaps the second load could be replaced by 2 vmov (one with q and the other with d if registers properly chosen) and thus improve cycle count.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen: It depends on the specific core you're targeting, but for high-power parts `VTBL` is really quite fast, and the most future-proof way to do this operation (i.e. `VTBL` isn't getting any slower as arm cores get more sophisticated--it will be single cycle on more and more processors).